# Auto indent & unindent for F#

Tags: f#, editor

I'm learning F# and I'm looking for an IDE or Editor that supports auto indent and some hotkey to unindent when done writing a function. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac right now and it does auto indent but then when I want to exit the function I have to backspace 3 or 4 times to go back to the starting column to exit the function. Just kind of a pain in the tuchus. Anyone have any advice (excluding suck it up).

Comment: There isn't any editor that does this automatically but vim and other editors have indent shortcuts.

Comment: I disagree with John Palmer: MOST sensible editors have a key to unindent when you're typing with spaces, although calling it a "hotkey" is a bit of a stretch, since it's backspace. The fact that Visual Studio does NOT do this is a bit of a WTF moment for me, frankly. It's such a basic feature that I'm gobsmacked that Visual Studio doesn't include it: VS Code does. But to get sensible backspace behavior back in Visual Studio, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jedmao.TabSanity-10817#review-details will help.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for F# work: install the Ionide plugin suite and you'll have a very nice F# dev environment. Ionide has three plugins in total: Ionide-fsharp is the main one, then there's Ionide-FAKE and Ionide-Paket to give you better integration with the FAKE and Paket tools.

Comment: In VS Shift+Tab is better than Backspace

Comment: Rider from JetBrains can also do this (tab, shift+Tab) also does code formatting, auto-indent. in VSCode you can use Ctrl+[ and Ctrl+].

Comment: Thanks for these really solid answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, various editors have various keyboard shortcuts that let you jump back to previous indentation level more rapidly than by hitting backspace four times.

For doing this automatically, I think this is potentially tricky (especially for unindentation), because the editor does not have any indication when you're finished writing a function. For example say you just typed:

```
let range lo hi = 
    [ lo .. hi ]
```

After you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the closing square bracket, you might either want to unindent and write another function, or you might want to continue indented with something like:

```
let range lo hi = 
    [ lo .. hi ]
    |> List.map formatNumber
```

So, doing this *automatically* is something that makes a lot of sense for curly-bracket languages, but it is not that obvious for languages like F# where indentation matters.

Comment: @Zee Fantastic, I'm glad the course is helping new people get interested in F#!